# What is the type or family of recsys algorithms for recommending similar users based on their interests?

Tags: recommendation-engine, collaborative-filtering

I am learning recommendation systems from Coursera MooC. I see there are majorly three types of filtering methods (in introduction course).
a. Content-based filtering
b. Item-Item collaborative filtering
c. User-User collaborative filtering

Having understood this, I am not sure where does the - *similar users recommendation based on the interests/preferences* belong to? For example, consider I have User->TopicsOfInterest0..n relation. I want to recommend other similar users based on their respective TopicsOfInterest (vector).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that these three types are an exhaustive classification of all recommender systems.

In fact, any matrix-factorization based algorithm (SVD, etc.) is both item-based and user-based at the same time. But the `TopicsOfInterest` (factors) are inferred automatically by the algorithm. For example, Apache Spark includes an implementation of the [alternating least squares (ALS)](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1608614) algorithm. Spark's [API](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.MatrixFactorizationModel) has the `userFeatures` method, which returns (roughly) a matrix, predicting users's attitude to each feature.

The only thing left to do is to compute a set of most similar users to a given one (e.g. find vectors, that are closest to a given one by [cosine similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity)).

Comment: Thanks for answer but I am still not sure what type of recommender it is? Is it hybrid (content-based & item-item filtering)? I think matching users to similar users - should be one of the common type of recommenders. I am asking for its classification or type, only so that I can read more relevant literature on that problem and also find a way to do it in Python.

Comment: Hi @Mikhail - could you please reply. Genuinely interested to know the answer. Thanks